# Eclipse complains method c_str could not be resolved

Tags: c++, eclipse, c++11, g++4.8

How can my program compile successfully but eclipse shows me "Semantic Errors" and how could I get rid of those errors?

The error messages I have are the following
`Method 'c_str' could not be resolved` (this happens also for compare and size on strings)

Here an example:

```
std::string someotherstring = "test";
std::string name = someotherstring.c_str();
```

The problem here is that it also creates follow up errors which seem all to be not true, my software compiles and runs as intended and even uses the "`c_str()`" returns to process messages. It seems only to be a display issue in Eclipse.

I have searched now for hours, tried to use a custom indexer but for some reason it won't go away. Maybe someone else has a good idea what to do here as Google spits out nothing about this specific problem. (I have even tried to use different C++11 standard flags as I thought it might had an impact)

Comment: This sounds like an eclipse problem and not a C++ problem?

Comment: @djechlin: If you're suggesting the C++ tags are not relevant (not sure if you are), I disagree. It's a problem with eclipse while using C++. A person using Java with eclipse probably doesn't have this same problem.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley C++ tags are relevant; but it should be made clearer that this is an Eclipse problem. I had to read the question a couple times to ascertain that; this should be clear before the question body is reached. So I edited the title.

Comment: Did you include `std::string`?  Is the compiler set up to use C++ (g++ not gcc)?

Comment: I have included <string> this should be more than sufficient? Correct me if i'm wrong. If you require additional info please tell me as i have tried everything possible within my knowledge.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. Solved by simply run a index -> rebuild. You can find that by clicking on the project main folder with the right button.
Cheers

Answer (score 1):

If you're building your projects using mingw and using C++11, you can not use the default dialect option of -std=c++0x.

Click on 'GCC C++ Compiler' and in the Command: textbox, enter -std=gnu++0x after the g++

Comment: this was asked 3 years ago ;) you might  be a little late

Comment: I just had the exact same issue with Eclipse CDT Kepler on the latest mingw, so it's still an applicable issue for anyone that comes looking.